# Como aparecer nas buscas do google (Erro 404 na raiz do site Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, seo, http-status-404

Olá, estou com um problema em um site feito em wordpress hospedado na hostigator. 
O site está em https://samos.com.br/mainsite.
Quando abro a página do site aparentemente tudo ocorre bem. Porém como há algum tempo o site não é indexado no google, fui investigar e percebi que **a raiz do site devolve um erro 404**:

Acredito que esse problema esteja impedindo o google de indexar o site. **Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como resolver?**

[image: Exemplo do problema 404 no network do stie]

Também ao fazer testes em sites de performance, obtenho o mesmo resultado:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https://samos.com.br/mainsite

https://www.webpagetest.org/

Veja também o .htaccess da raiz do dominio:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://samos.com.br/$1 [R,L]`
```

E o .htaccess no site /mainsite :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Qualquer dica é bem-vinda.

Answer (score 1):

Você utiliza plugins de cache? já olhou os seus links permanentes? 
Tente marcar a sua página "home" como "*página inicial estática*" em **Configurações de Leitura**, se não funcionar, refazer o seu sitemap.xml pode te ajudar a resolver.

Comment: Consegui resolver a questão do erro 404 da seguinte forma: atualizei o wordpress, atualizei os plugins, não havia plugin de cache. Depois vi que nas configurações o tema redirecionava as páginas 404 para a home, e o tema ocultava essa página das buscas.

Estou tentando agora fazer a página aparecer nas buscas, tem alguma sugestão?


https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJXPW.png